# use canvas.drawBitmap in AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-canvas

i use async task to draw bitmap on view,but it's draw nothing!
this is the asynctask code

```
class BitmapWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{

    private Canvas canvas;
    private Rect rcText;
    private Paint paint;
    private Options options;
    private Options opt;
    public BitmapWorker(Canvas canvas,Rect rcText,Paint paint)
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.rcText = rcText;//the bitmap must draw on it's rect
        this.paint = paint;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_AttachSource, options);
        opt = new Options();
        opt.inPurgeable = true;
        opt.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, INSAMPLESIZE_THIMBPIC_WIDTH, INSAMPLESIZE_THIMBPIC_HEIGHT);

        LoadThumbPic(m_AttachSource, opt);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Boolean hasBitmap = false;
        while(!hasBitmap)
        {
            if(m_PictureMessageTumbPic.get() != null)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(m_PictureMessageTumbPic.get(), null, rcText, paint);
                hasBitmap = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Options opt = new Options();
                opt.inPurgeable = true;
                opt.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, INSAMPLESIZE_THIMBPIC_WIDTH, INSAMPLESIZE_THIMBPIC_HEIGHT);
                LoadThumbPic(m_AttachSource, opt);
                canvas.drawBitmap(m_PictureMessageTumbPic.get(), null, rcText, paint);
                hasBitmap = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

tnx 4 adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you are drawing to a view, but from your code, it appears that you have not [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) the view after the drawing operation. So you have to modify the `AsyncTask` to take in the `View`, and call its `invalidate()` method after you've updated the Canvas.

Remember that modern OS caches graphics elements to improve performance, so you have to use the mechanism it provided to notify it that an update is in order.

Try this (have not run the code, may have silly errors):

```
class BitmapWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{

    private Canvas canvas;
    private Rect rcText;
    private Paint paint;
    private Options options;
    private Options opt;
    private View view;
    public BitmapWorker(Canvas canvas,Rect rcText,Paint paint, View view)
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.rcText = rcText;//the bitmap must draw on it's rect
        this.paint = paint;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_AttachSource, options);
        opt = new Options();
        opt.inPurgeable = true;
        opt.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, INSAMPLESIZE_THIMBPIC_WIDTH, INSAMPLESIZE_THIMBPIC_HEIGHT);

        LoadThumbPic(m_AttachSource, opt);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Boolean hasBitmap = false;
        while(!hasBitmap)
        {
            if(m_PictureMessageTumbPic.get() != null)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(m_PictureMessageTumbPic.get(), null, rcText, paint);
                hasBitmap = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Options opt = new Options();
                opt.inPurgeable = true;
                opt.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, INSAMPLESIZE_THIMBPIC_WIDTH, INSAMPLESIZE_THIMBPIC_HEIGHT);
                LoadThumbPic(m_AttachSource, opt);
                canvas.drawBitmap(m_PictureMessageTumbPic.get(), null, rcText, paint);
                hasBitmap = true;
            }
        }

        if(hasBitmap) {
            view.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so how can i prevent to running again asyncTask when invalidate views?

Comment: Sorry... I do quite understand what you mean, but I'll update my answer to include a sample code of what to try in a few min

Comment: if i use invalidate,it's clear the view and must use canvas.DrawBtmap again to draw bitmap on it,is it correct?

Comment: You should draw the Bitmap in that view's onDraw() method. I am assuming it's a custom view.

Comment: yes it's custom view and finally i change the method,load bitmap in asyntask and draw it on main thread,tnx for helping

Answer (score 1):

Make this on your `onPostExecute` method:

- Get the surface holder.
- Initialise a Canvas from a Holder.
- Make the holder unlock your canvas and post the canvas.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
    Canvas canvas = null;

    try {
        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(result, 50, 50, paint);
        }

    } finally {
        if (canvas != null)
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```